# JDBC Connection URL For Embedded Derby in a Webapp

Tags: java, web-applications, jdbc, derby, embedded-database

I have a derby database that is deployed along with my webapp to WEB-INF/classes/myDb

What should my jdbc.connection url be to connect so that I can write to the database?

I am trying

```
jdbc:derby:myDb;
```

and it can not find the database.  I need to be able to modify the database.  If i put classpath:myDb, it finds it, but it is unfortunately read only per the derby docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i solved it by setting my jdbc connection url at runtime and using:

```
        StringBuilder derbyUrl = new StringBuilder("jdbc:derby:");
        derbyUrl.append(servletContext.getRealPath("/"));
        derbyUrl.append("/WEB-INF/classes/myDb;");
        dataSource.setUrl(derbyUrl.toString());
```

Comment: +1: I've had to do very similar things myself (my solution was a custom Spring factory class did the rewrite, but that's conceptually almost identical) and I've yet to see any substantially-better ideas. Mind you, you might also make the argument that in a production deployment, the webapp files shouldn't be writable at all, so requiring an external database connection instead…